# Move the object in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to ask a question about the iPhone application. I am going to write a application, and the application can let the users to move the list or folder just like you move the app in the home page in iPhone. Is it possible to do it? Thank you.

Comment: Since the home page does, it, it is obviously possible. There is no out-of-the-box Xcode widget you can just drop in, however, so it's a lot of work to emulate the same behaviour ... more than anyone is likely to paste into an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to move stuff like moving the app in the home page. It can be hard but it is possible. You need to handle all the touch events inside your view controller and then decide to move stuff. There is no built-in ViewController for doing that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is possible. So the answer to your question is: Yes.

But I don't think that's what you wanted to know - there's no convenient or existing way to implement something like this, you would have to do it all by yourself.